# For a given feature find the closest point along a given path

Tags: open-source-gis, point, geotools, linear-referencing, linestring

Looking for a Java based (foss4g) solution for the following:

I am using a path along with a buffer to find features that are along the path. For each of the features returned I want to find the coordinate that is best fit ... meaning a straight line from the feature to the path and gleaning the point on the path.

Comment: What software do you want to use?

Comment: I am already using GeoTools and would like to stick with that if possible ... definitely a Java based solution would be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Java, I'd recommend [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). There is both a "Nearest Point" and "Closest Point" routine (I'm not sure if it is the same, or was renamed between versions) that does what you want.
[image: JTS]

The result from the above is `LINESTRING (205 305, 250 300)`, so the first point of the result is your closest point coordinates, and the length property of the result is the distance.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTDOC/Closest+Point+on+a+Line seems to discuss the solution to your problem.

--- update by author of that page --

This page has been ported to sphinx based documentation:

- http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/snap.html

That page just goes through how the JTS classes for snapping to a line can be used.

Comment: LocationIndexedLine is looking very promising ...